# editor substitutes class=data-ck-unsafe-element for custom tag

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have created a custom ckeditor5 plugin (run with Drupal 9) and that all works fine for initial editing and output. It creates a custom tag: `<bbref ver="RSV">Ex 2:32</bbref>`

A couple of days later the editor now rejects my tag when it loads saved HTML and replaces it with `<span data-ck-unsafe-element="bbref"></span>`

This seems to occur in ckeditor's domconverter.js

There is a method for handling a similar thing with data-ck-unsafe-attribute-   (eg https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/updating/guides/update-to-31.html#the-table-and-tablecell-attributes-names-change)  but not for unsafe-element and trying the unsafe-attribute method does not seem to work.
I'm using the createAttributeElement() function in downcast (from the abbreviation plugin)

Answer (score -1):

In Drupal ckeditor is configured in 'Text formats and editors'
This includes a filter 'Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML'
If this is enabled the problem goes away...